# Insert nested json array into multiple tables in sql server

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have following Json Object in Sql server. I want to insert this data into multiple tables with their relation (i.e. foreign key):

```
DECLARE @JsonObject NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{  
   "FirstElement":{  
      "Name":"ABC",
      "Location":"East US",
      "Region":"West US",
      "InnerElement":[
         {  
            "Name":"IE1",
            "Description":"IE1 Description",
            "Type":"Small",
            "InnerMostElement":[  
               {
                  "Key":"Name",
                  "Value":"IME1"
               },
                {
                  "Key":"AnotherProperty",
                  "Value":"Value1"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "Name":"IE2",
            "Description":"IE2 Description",
            "Type":"Medium",
            "InnerMostElement":[ 
               {
                  "Key":"Name",
                  "Value":"IME2"
               },
                {
                  "Key":"Address",
                  "Value":"Xyz"
               }, 
               {
                  "Key":"Type",
                  "Value":"Simple"
               },
                {
                  "Key":"LastProperty",
                  "Value":"ValueX"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}'
```

The table structure is attached here:

[image]

I want to insert the **FirstElement** data in **Table1**, **InnerElement** data in **Table2** and **InnerMostElement** data in **Table3**.

Comment: This question is much more convenient to answer if you include `CREATE TABLE` statements for all the tables, including the `IDENTITY` columns that appear to be missing.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I do have IDENTITY columns in the table. I forgot to mention here. How do I loop on this json object?

Comment: You don't, because loops in T-SQL suck. Unless your JSON is extremely large, a set-based solution (like the one in my answer) is almost certainly superior. For a very large JSON, a cursor solution may be worth it so all the parsing is only done once, but if that's a concern you'd probably want to move the parsing outside SQL Server and into the client anyway.

Answer (score 6):

The easy part is the first table, because we're only inserting one row and it has no dependencies:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT Table1([Name], [Location], [Region])
SELECT [Name], [Location], [Region]
FROM OPENJSON(@JsonObject, '$.FirstElement')
WITH (
    [Name] VARCHAR(100),
    [Location] VARCHAR(100),
    [Region] VARCHAR(100)
);

DECLARE @Table1Id INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

The hard part is the next table. We need to capture all the identities of the inserted rows, but also all the data yet to be inserted into table 3. Because the `OUTPUT` clause of `INSERT` is restricted to outputting values in the base table only, we need to use `MERGE` trickery:

```
DECLARE @Table3Input TABLE([Table2Id] INT, [InnerMostElement] NVARCHAR(MAX));

MERGE Table2
USING (
    SELECT [Name], [Description], [Type], [InnerMostElement]
    FROM OPENJSON(@JsonObject, '$.FirstElement.InnerElement')
    WITH (
        [Name] VARCHAR(100),
        [Description] VARCHAR(100),
        [Type] VARCHAR(100),
        [InnerMostElement] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
    )
) AS J
ON 1 = 0    -- Always INSERT
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT([Table1Id], [Name], [Description], [Type])
    VALUES (@Table1Id, J.[Name], J.[Description], J.[Type])
    OUTPUT inserted.Id, J.[InnerMostElement]
    INTO @Table3Input([Table2Id], [InnerMostElement]);
```

If the tables are to be primarily filled using JSON, it may be more convenient to use `SEQUENCE` objects to generate consecutive values (using `sp_sequence_get_range`) without the need to capture the whole JSON into a temporary table. That would greatly simplify this and remove the need for `MERGE`.

The last table is easy again:

```
INSERT Table3([Table2Id], [Key], [Value])
SELECT [Table2Id], KV.[Key], KV.[Value]
FROM @Table3Input CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT [Key], [Value]
    FROM OPENJSON([InnerMostElement])
    WITH (
        [Key] VARCHAR(100),
        [Value] VARCHAR(100)
    )
) AS KV;

COMMIT;
```

The transaction is logically necessary to ensure this object is entirely inserted, or not at all.

Final output:

```
+----+------+----------+---------+
| Id | Name | Location | Region  |
+----+------+----------+---------+
|  1 | ABC  | East US  | West US |
+----+------+----------+---------+
```

```
+----+----------+------+-----------------+--------+
| Id | Table1Id | Name |   Description   |  Type  |
+----+----------+------+-----------------+--------+
|  1 |        1 | IE1  | IE1 Description | Small  |
|  2 |        1 | IE2  | IE2 Description | Medium |
+----+----------+------+-----------------+--------+
```

```
+----+----------+-----------------+--------+
| Id | Table2Id |       Key       | Value  |
+----+----------+-----------------+--------+
|  1 |        1 | Name            | IME1   |
|  2 |        1 | AnotherProperty | Value1 |
|  3 |        2 | Name            | IME2   |
|  4 |        2 | Address         | Xyz    |
|  5 |        2 | Type            | Simple |
|  6 |        2 | LastProperty    | ValueX |
+----+----------+-----------------+--------+
```

For completeness, here's how you'd turn that back into JSON:

```
SELECT 
  [Name] AS 'FirstElement.Name', 
  [Location] AS 'FirstElement.Location', 
  [Region] AS 'FirstElement.Region',
  (
    SELECT 
      [Name], 
      [Description], 
      [Type],
      (
        SELECT 
          [Key], 
          [Value]
        FROM Table3
        WHERE Table3.Table2Id = Table2.Id
        FOR JSON PATH
      ) AS 'InnerMostElement'
    FROM Table2
    WHERE Table2.Table1Id = Table1.Id
    FOR JSON PATH
  ) AS 'FirstElement.InnerElement'
FROM Table1
FOR JSON PATH;
```