# I want to insert this data into multiple tables from Json file into Sql table with their relation (foreign key) and link all data to one master table

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2016-express

Database will be having identity linked to each level of SQL. Also would like to merge data of all three table into one master table Table_master which will have final number of data based on inner element record id 2.

expected to update data into table of SQL Server 2016
Table structure with use of Foreign key
Also how to export same data into Json back again in a shared network drive folder.

[Expected data to be updated in Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIVFL.jpg)

Repro Code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Table1') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1
    (
    Name VARCHAR(100), Location VARCHAR(100), Region VARCHAR(100) 
    )


DECLARE @MYJSON VARCHAR(1000)

SET @MYJSON = '
{
  "Name":"ABC",
  "Location":"East US",
  "Region":"West US",
  "Element":
 [
     {  
        "Name":"IE1",
        "Description":"IE1 Description",
        "Type":"Small",
        "InnerElement":
        [ 
           { "Key":"Name", "Value":"IME1"},
           {"Key":"AnotherProperty","Value":"Value1"}
        ]
     },
     {  
        "Name":"IE2",
        "Description":"IE2 Description",
        "Type":"Medium",
        "InnerElement":
        [ 
           {"Key":"Name","Value":"IME2"},
           {"Key":"Address","Value":"Xyz"}, 
           {"Key":"Type","Value":"Simple"},
           {"Key":"LastProperty","Value":"ValueX"}
        ]
     }
 ]}
 '

SELECT 
JSON_VALUE(@MYJSON,'$.Name') As Name,
JSON_VALUE(@MYJSON,'$.Location') As Location,
JSON_VALUE(@MYJSON,'$.Region') As Region
```

Comment: Please 1. Represent the data as text, not pictures; 2. Tag the actual database you are using, and what integration tool you want to use. 3. Show what you've tried

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I am unable to solve this I have refer following
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729243/insert-nested-json-array-into-multiple-tables-in-sql-server?answertab=oldest#tab-top 
 solution but unable to achieve what I am expecting to. If possible can you help me through.

Comment: I have edited your question and added some code. Can you add the other table creation definitions and any code that you have actually tried so far. This allows us to quickly copy/paste into our dev environments to assist. You are less likely to help if you don't provide an easy starting point (a repro). Also, not having a repro implies that you haven't tried anything.

Comment: Also, note in your referenced question, the very first comment is _much more convenient to answer if you include CREATE TABLE statements for all the tables_

Comment: Hi Nick! My approach to this is to use a BULK Column function to import data from a folder for JSON. Currently I am unable to share my SQL Query file as I am still trying. Now I am facing issue of not getting data file open and import due OS access problem.

Comment: I suggest you ask that as a different question. You can stop that being a blocker and continue with this question if you take the time to edit your question and create a repro. The repro I started for you stores JSON in a variable so avoids that issue

Comment: I will be able to share my part of code after 24 hrs of this

Answer (score 0):

```
USE JSON_CAT GO DECLARE @JsonObject NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT @JsonObject=BulkColumn from  openrowset  (BULK 'C:\Users\uverma\Desktop\Test.Json, SINGLE_CLOB)T 
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT Table1([Name], [Location], [Region])
SELECT [Name], [Location], [Region]
FROM OPENJSON(@JsonObject, '$.InnerElement')
WITH (    [Name] VARCHAR(100),    [Location] VARCHAR(100),    [Region] VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @Table1Id INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
DECLARE @Table3Input TABLE([Table2Id] INT, [InnerMostElement] NVARCHAR(MAX));
MERGE Table2
USING (    SELECT [Name], [Description], [Type], [InnerMostElement]    
FROM OPENJSON(@JsonObject, '$.InnerElement')    
WITH (        [Name] VARCHAR(100),        [Description] VARCHAR(100),        [Type] VARCHAR(100),        [InnerMostElement] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON    )) AS J 
ON 1 = 0    
-- Always INSERT
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN     
INSERT([Table1Id], [Name], [Description], [Type])    
VALUES (@Table1Id, J.[Name], J.[Description], J.[Type])    
OUTPUT inserted.Id, J.[InnerMostElement]    
INTO @Table3Input([Table2Id], [InnerMostElement]);  

INSERT Table3([Table2Id], [Key], [Value]) 
SELECT [Table2Id], KV.[Key], KV.[Value] 
FROM @Table3Input 
CROSS APPLY (    SELECT [Key], [Value]    
FROM OPENJSON([InnerMostElement])    
WITH (        [Key] VARCHAR(100),[Value] VARCHAR(100))) AS KV;

COMMIT;
```

Please see I have tried with this and my data is importing as well but value inserting in database are becoming null

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid please see i have used above query to get data. data getting inserted as null.

Comment: But I am not getting expected result.

Comment: Thank you Nick with my above SQL code i got my expected result.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Can you help how I can read multiple Json files into SQL.

Comment: Where is the list of JSON files? You just reuse the above and loop around them.

Comment: Multiple Json files are stored on my local drive and needs to be read using my above solution and update in my db. I want to understand how exactly I can loop to read the data. Can you refer me some video or document how to include in my above sql query? List of Json can be like Test001.json to n number of json files.

Comment: How can i read a json file using SQL where JSON file naming is "abc_cd_000012347934_20200717201054.json"  both numerical value will be varriable.

Comment: The problem is that SQL has to already know the name of the files so it can explicitly import them by filename. You could try using `xp_dirtree` but this is usually disabled on most systems https://www.patrickkeisler.com/2012/11/how-to-use-xpdirtree-to-list-all-files.html